# How to get bootstrap v4alpha6 navigation list to justify right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So apparently the alpha 6 version of bootstrap 4 has gone all flex, which has broken some of the stuff I was using in alpha 5. As per [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbpwffk1/) , I'm trying to get the flex justification class to put the navigation bar content over on the right, like so:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
```

Inspecting the elemnt shows that is has the `justify-content: flex-end !important;` on it, so I would have expected it to work. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Do you want everything right of the brand name aligned right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To right align the `.navbar-nav` on desktop devices you need to place the `.justify-content-end` class on its parent:

- add `.justify-content-end` class to `#navbarSupportedContent`.

---

If you want to right align the mobile menu on the right side:

- `.text-right` (instead of `.justify-content-end`) on your `.navbar-nav` and
- `.justify-content-end` on your `.form-inline`.

---

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#replaceThisWithYourOwnId" aria-controls="replaceThisWithYourOwnId" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BrandName</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="replaceThisWithYourOwnId">
    <ul class="navbar-nav text-right">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link ">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 justify-content-end">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I know this is out of the question, but want to ask you that the doc has no explanation on classes like my-2 and my-*. So how do you learn to use them? Just copy pasting it doesn't feel right for me. . Regards.

Comment: Ho no no , I was talking about `<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>` where classes like `my-2`, `my-sm-0` have no documentation

Comment: Bro, check the documentation and even in your one answer

Comment: @TilakMaddy [`Here it is`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/). `my-` stands for `margin-y` = `margin-top` + `margin-bottom`. You can also use `mx-`, `ma-`, `pa-`, `px-`, `py-`, etc...